# How to make sure all models have access to service agents?

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, model

I have a WPF client in MVVM architecture.

The WPP client needs to connect to a WCF service, and send operations to it.

This ability needs to be from different views, thus meaning different models (right ?)

***Questions:***

1. Is my assumption, that the **models** are the ones who access the WCF service client - correct ? Meaning - we do not want the view or the model-view to connect to the WCF service, right ? only the models themselves...
2. How do I make sure that all the models have access to the WCF service's client ? Do I use some kind of 'ServiceLocator' ? (I have read the term somewhere, but do not know what it means exactly. Would be happy if someone who has done this before can shed some light on the topic).

Comment: A tip: just because you have heard about a term doesn't mean that it is necessarily good.  Many consider the Service Locator an anti-pattern: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Model represents a data, so ViewModel should be aware of services
2. Just make a `IMyWcfService` as a dependency of any ViewModel, to accomplish that you can make `ViewModelBase` abstract class with protected constructor which accepts `IMyWcfService` so all concrete ViewModels will be obligated to provide this service

And as already stated in comments - try to avoid service locator, this would mess up API and unit testing. Just provide all dependencies as constructor arguments this woudl make a class API more clear so you will see what is required and do not worry about run time errors like "service locator unable to resolve a service"

Comment: and when do the service clients get instantiated ? when the ViewModel is created ? what about the MainWindowViewModel ? it is always visible - so should it's client always be 'connected' ? (I was told that this is a bad idea, and that in WCF - a client should be created only for the duration of the call)

Comment: moreover - I have a specific service that my WPF application ALWAYS needs to be connected to (for notifications using ICallback). I am not sure where I should instantiate it...

Comment: You should instantiate it before an actual call, or if it will be used anyway - instantiate it on the top level of your application, regarding availability for the duration of the call - this is an other question

Comment: you say I should instantiate it in the top level of the application ? is this done in the 'App.xaml.cs' ? how does the 'App.xaml.cs' have access to all the services ? it seems strange that the 'App.xaml.cs' instantiates the services, while the ViewModels are the ones who are going to use it ... and another thing - I will have a 'Login' window - where the user will input a username and password, that will be used to connect to the service(s). This means that I cannot connect to the services during the application startup. This needs to happen in the 'LoginViewModel', no ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I do not mean App.xaml.cs level. I mean a top level where your business objects come to the scene, basically where main services/main viewModel get instantiated

Comment: and where does that happen ? I am new to MVVM, so I am not sure where this happens...

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't think `Models` should be anything more than plain container objects to hold data. They should not contain data access code, or any other application logic other than perhaps basic data validation to verify its data integrity.

Your `ViewModels` should be the ones responsible for talking with the WCF server. Or better yet, make a repository class that contains all your data access calls, and have your ViewModel use that instead.

Don't forget that with MVVM, your `ViewModels` *are* your application. They're responsible for everything from application flow, to business logic, to data access (although sometimes these concepts are abstracted out of the VM, such as using a Repository for data access).

`Views` are just a user-friendly interface that sits on top of the ViewModels to allow users to interact with them, and `Models` are just objects used to contain data.